# How can I change default play/pause icon(for android 13) in notification panel which by default comes with PlaybackStateCompat?

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-mediaplayer

[play/pause icon with red marker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kOCZs.jpg)

I want to change the icon. I tried removing PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_PLAY and adding customAction, but getting as expected. after adding custom action PlaybackStateBuilder the icon gets displayed like the suffle button in that image.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the drawable icon in the notification while creating the notification.

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder builder = MediaStyleHelper.from(BackgroundAudioService.this, mMediaSessionCompat, CHANNEL_ID);
builder.addAction(new NotificationCompat.Action(R.drawable.ic_skip_pause, "Pause", MediaButtonReceiver.buildMediaButtonPendingIntent(this, PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_PLAY_PAUSE)));
```

in above example `R.drawable.ic_skip_paue` is the drawalble you have to change